# Proof of harmonic series - please explain the reasoning behind each step of this proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series, divergence-operator

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the reasoning behind each step of this proof of the divergence of the harmonic series. I have made significant efforts to try and understand it but to no avail.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I won't go through all the proof for you. And neither will anyone else on this site, if my experience is anything to go on. Please, point us to the step of the proof that is unclear.

Comment: And if you right now want to say "none of the steps is clear to me", then re-read, carefully, the whole thing. Because the "nothing is clear" situation can only be the result of lazy reading.

Comment: The first point of struggle is in understanding why it is using subsequences. What information is it attempting to convey? How are subsequences helping to convey this message?

Comment: @ThePointer: No, the _first_ step is actually to understand how the proof works before you can usefully start asking, "why was it written that way and not in some different way?".

Comment: @5xum As I said, I have made significant efforts to understand this proof. I am not asking to be spoon-fed before making any effort on my own. I have dedicated hours of effort and made no progress in understanding this. At this point, my options are (1) skip the proof and leave a gap in my knowledge that will come back to haunt me later on, or (2) ask the good people here to hold my hand through it.

Comment: @ThePointer: Yes, you're asking to be spoon-fed, because you're just dumping an image into your question with no text of your own. The "significant effort" you claim to have spent does not help any reader of your question understand what it is you need to have explained as long as you're keeping it secret what you got out of that "significant effort" and where you're stuck in your understanding. If you have a question _about_ the proof, **actually ask that question**, instead of asking to have the entire thing spoon-fed to you in the hope that someone will randomly come up with a spoon ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm This is a first-year college math course. In high school and undergraduate mathematics, there is no class that focuses on how to reason about proofs. If you can offer insight, I will be thankful.

Comment: .. portion that contains the point that you need help with but are keeping secret what is.

Comment: @ThePointer OK, I apologize. 99% of the time, questions like these are made by people who put in zero effort. Still, your question should have been more exact - which part is clear and which is not. I gave an answer about the part of the question that you explicitly mentioned below.

Comment: @ThePointer: I can offer no insight as long as you insist on keeping it secret which question you have about the proof you're quoting.

Comment: @ThePointer you said "In high school and undergraduate mathematics, there is no class that focuses on how to reason about proofs" and unfortunately that's  true, for what I know about anglosaxon schools. As your comments demonstrate, now you are concentrating on this topic a lot of questions on each single step, that even the answer by *5xsum* couldn't help you to solve. It seems you would need actually to be helped gradually, step by step, but this is not the place for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is using subsequences because

> If $a_1, a_2,a_3\dots$ is an increasing sequence and there exists some unbounded subsequence $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, a_{i_3}\dots$, then the original subsequence is unbounded.

You can prove this quite easily by:

- Take any $M\in\mathbb R$
- Because $a_{i_1}, a_{i_2}, a_{i_3}\dots$ is unbounded, there exists some $k$ such that $a_{i_k} > M$.
- Take $n=i_k$
- Then, $a_n>M$.

Therefore, for every $M\in\mathbb R$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n>M$, and therefore the sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ is unbounded.

---

In the particular case of your harmonic series, $s_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ elements of the series, and $i_k = 2^k$. The proof shows that $$s_1,s_2,s_4,s_8,\dots$$ is an unbounded sequence, and concludes that $$s_1,s_2,s_3,\dots$$ must also be an unbounded sequence.

---

Now, is there any other step in the proof that is unclear?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48120/discussion-on-answer-by-5xum-proof-of-harmonic-series-please-explain-the-reaso).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for waiting until the end of the discussion.